# SharePoint online reader role in Admin Center

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, roles, sharepoint-admin-center

Is there any role in o365 admin center that can be designated only reader access for SharePoint Admin center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS has just released an update that Sharepoint online reader role will be avaibale from march 2020

Answer (score 0):

> A little late to the party but I was looking into the same thing and
>   found this:
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/add-users/about-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide
>
> You can set them as a Global Reader in customized admin. This does
>   exactly what you need. Maybe it was a recent addition in the last 6
>   months but it's there now.

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/494502aa-2025-4d9a-a9a4-7ffd45ed0aed/office-365-admin-center-read-only-permissions?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

You can assign ***Global reader*** role - Has read-only access to all management features and most data in all admin centers. Assign the global reader role to users who need to view admin features and settings in all admin centers that the global admin can view. The global reader admin can't edit any settings.

Comment: Global reader role doesnt apply to sharepoint, Privileged Access Management, Customer Lockbox, sensitivity labels, or the following features within Teams: Teams Lifecycle, Reporting & Call Analytics, IP Phone Device Management, and App Catalog.

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests and Global Reader will not be an option. For that, If you want to grant read-only permission in SharePoint sites, you will need to grant the permission in that site. Admin role in admin center will not work for that.

Comment: i would like to have a read only permission for sharepoint admin center not sharepoint sites.